# Center align product name and price on woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone know how to center align product name and price on woocommerce?
I have tried

```
/* Center product elements on shop pages */
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
text-align:center;
}
.woocommerce .products .star-rating, .woocommerce-page .products .star-rating {
float:none;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

and

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product h3
{text-align: center;}
```

Thanks

Comment: I suppose posting the matching html including the parent-object (with it's css) would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Spent all night trying to find this myself. This seems to work for me:

```
.woocommerce .products .product,
.woocommerce .products .product .price
{text-align:center}
```

Comment: Did you add this to the custom css or the default one?